# Azure SQL Data Warehouse - Strange DateTime conversion error/ behaviour

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-synapse, sql-date-functions, sql-convert

I am reading data from data lake (csv) and when running the below query, I am getting a **'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string'** error message.

```
    select convert(datetime, NullIf(ltrim(rtrim([Date started])), ''), 111)
    FROM dl.temp
```

Looked through the data and checked the source file as well, couldn't spot anything unusual.

As soon as I include the * and change the query to the below everything runs fine and the conversion seem to be doing its job.

```
    select convert(datetime, NullIf(ltrim(rtrim([Date started])), ''), 111),*
    from dl.temp
```

Out of curiosity also wanted to check the max and minimum date, so running max gives me the following:

[image]

However when I search for that particular value like below, I don't get any rows returned. It seems like it setting it to the column name. Does anyone know what is going on?

```
    select *
    from dl.temp
    where [Date started] = 'Date started'
```

I am running this against an Azure Data Warehouse.

Comment: just looks like your csv might have a header row and you're importing that as well... try `select * from dl.temp where [Date started] like '%Date started%'`

Comment: Try running the following: `SELECT [Date started] FROM dl.temp WHERE TRY_CONVERT(date,[Date started]) IS NULL;`.

Comment: @JamieD77 already tried it, doesn't return any row

Comment: @Larnu the TRY_CONVERT function is not available in Azure Databases yet

Comment: (Wrong link before). It is in Azure SQL Databas, not in Azure SQL Data Warehouse. At least according to the article: [`TRY_CONVERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql). If you're using Azure SQL Data Warehouse, rather than Azure SQL Database, could you please update your tags accordingly? :)

Comment: @Larnu, updated tags. I am using Azure SQL Data Warehouse to be clear

Comment: Is `dl.temp` an external table? Does the file have a header row?

Comment: @GregGalloway, yes it is an external table. It does have a header row and first row gets rejected

Comment: @Sharingan but your max() screenshot contradicts that statement. Are you load multiple files? Can you provide the `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE` statement?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find the issue is in your external file format.

In the CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT you probably need to add FIRST_ROW=2 in your FORMAT OPTIONS.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-file-format-transact-sql